# PHP and MySQL - how to update single row from single table using order by desc and limit 1

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys actually i am trying to maintain user logs with ip, last login time and last logout time of users, working in php and mysql. successfully stored ip and login time while user logs in but while updating logout time at the time of logout it updated all logout time for the same user id and i want to update only last logout time of the user id whether he logged in any no of times. can any one help me for the same.

my code is  -

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && !empty($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    include "connection.php";
    $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];

    $sqluserlogs = "UPDATE userlogs SET LastLogout = now()
    WHERE uid = '$userId' ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 1";

    if (mysql_query($sqluserlogs, $conn)) {
        //echo 'success';
    } else {
        //echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

updated query -

```
  $sqluserlogs = "UPDATE userlogs SET LastLogout = now() WHERE
   uid = '$userId' ORDER BY ulogID DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to unterstand your question. Why do you use `order` and `limit` in an update statement? Try to make  `$userId` unique in your table and you'll always update just one record.

Comment: Store the session id in the user log as well and use that to update the log.

Comment: Don't use the _deprecated and insecure_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks @user1915746 , i did the same and now it works

Comment: If the user id is unique, you can only have one log entry per user.

Comment: i have updated my question with working query. thanks every one for suggestions and comment

Answer (score 0):

Try a join:

```
 "UPDATE userlogs AS UpdateTable
     INNER JOIN (
         SELECT JoinTable.id
         FROM userlogs AS JoinTable
         WHERE JoinTable.uid = '$userId'
         ORDER BY uid DESC
         LIMIT 1) 
                 AS source ON source.id = UpdateTable.id
    SET LastLogout = now()";
```